# Streaming video with ec2 instance T2 micro

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, streaming

Hy im streaming video using amazon s3 buckets,cloudfront and ec2 instance free tier using node.js ,but the streaming is very slow ,is it because of the free tier ,will upgrading the ec2 instance speed up the streaming ,please help

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EC2 `t2.micro` instances have "Low to Moderate" network bandwidth. This is likely causing a bottleneck.

I recommend moving to the `T3` family of instances, which have higher network bandwidth.

I also recommend that you try various instance types to see whether this fixes the problem. They are only charged by the second, so it will not cost much to try them.